# How to specify text as integer c++?

Tags: c++, integer

Im newbie in c++ programming. How can I do something like this?..

```
int question1;

question1: "What is your name?";
```

to set the text value in integer?

Comment: `cout >> "Name: "; char* c=malloc(256); c << cin; int a=atoi(c);` --> will give 0 if your name doesn't start with a number

Comment: You cannot? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: How would a name be an integer?

Comment: @ForceBru: Your code still won't compile and `c` is (or was) an uninitialized pointer. Yuck

Comment: @ForceBru, please add that as an answer so I can downvote it ;-) That is totally invalid, nonsense C++.

Comment: You want to have a name as a number ? Nonsense I think.

Comment: @NavidEMAD - not unless you are a slave, your actual name is irrelevant or long forgotten and you are being addressed by the number your owner gave you. Or an evil genius assistant - think Dr. Evil and N2

Comment: No I was looking for string. I forgot that integer is only for numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "What is your name?: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Your Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cin.get( );
    return 0;
}
```

Simply read the input in as string.

Comment: Thanks! I already have tried that but I forgot to include string.